# Error in wing IDE: no module named "sympy"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sympy, wing-ide

I used sublime text till now for python, but today I installed wing personal for python.
I installed the module "sympy" both manually and by pip. I worked fine in sublime text, but when I wrote `import sympy` in the wing ide, it showed this error:
`builtins.ImportError: No module named sympy`. What is happening?
I use wing personal, os: windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Show Python Environment in the Source menu and compare the interpreter there to the value of sys.executable (after 'import sys') in Python outside of Wing or in Sublime.  You are probably not using the same interpreter.

This can be changed from Project Properties in the Project menu by setting Python Executable under the Environment tab:

If you're using a base install of Python then select Command Line and select the interpreter from the drop down or enter the full path to python or python.exe.

If you're using a virtualenv you can also do that and enter the virtualenv's Python or select Activated Env and enter the path to the virtualenv's activate.